# Make Docker4Mac and vagrant see each others network

Tags: docker, vagrant, docker-machine, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I have API which runs in **vagrant** and I have consumers which run in **docker containers**.

The thing is that previously, with **docker-machine** I was able to put vagrant and docker-machine into same network rather easy.

With **Docker Desktop for Mac it seems** a little bit difficult to do it in some automated way. At this moment what I am doing is I add my vagrant host as alias for `l0`.

What would be the way to make life easier?